# Array from child to be used by parent

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have the array avg_temps, which comes from a child process; I wish to copy this to the pointer arr so that the parent process can access the array as well. Can someone lend me a hand? The idea is to be able to compute something from the child and from the parent process, only using files (no other mechanism is allowed, i.e. no pipes, no shared memory, no message passing)

```
#include <string.h>

int main (){
  
  double avg_temps[6];
  double avg_time = 5;


  if (pid ==0) { \child ...
  double *arr[6];
  
  
  for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
    avg_temps[i] = avg_time*i;
  }
  
  *arr = avg_temps;

  } else { //parent
  double newarr[6];
  memcpy(newarr, &arr, 6);

  }

  
  
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "comes from a child process"?  The parent and child do not share an address space. Have the child write the data to a pipe and let the parent read it.

Comment: Cannot use pipes, shared memory nor message passing, only allowed to use files.

Comment: Why the array of pointers?  That just makes the code more complex..

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right, but still not sure how to address the problem

Comment: You need code in the child to write the data to a file; you need code in the parent to read the data from the file.  You need some way to know that the child has finished writing — it might be sufficient to wait for the child to die (it isn't going to write any more after it is dead).  The parent and child need to agree on the file name.

Comment: Correct, that's what I'm doing. The thing is that I need to compute something derived from both processes, but not in the file (now that I think about it). So, I'll create a pipe to get this sorted. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

```
    const avg_temps_size = 6;
    double avg_temps[avg_temps_size]; /* This is the shared array */
    char tmpname[60];
    sprintf(tmpname, "/tmp/%d.tmp", getpid());
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork() < 0) {
        /* Error handler. */
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        /* Do something that initialized array */
        FILE *f = fopen(tmpname, "wb");
        if (!f) {
            /* Error handler. */
        }
        if (fwrite(avg_temps, avg_temps_size * sizeof(double), 1, f) != 1) {
            /* Error handler. */
        }
        if (fclose(f)) {
            /* Error handler. */
            /* Not everything was written */
        }
    } else {
        int wstatus;
        waitpid(pid, &wstatus, 0);
        FILE *f = fopen(tmpname, "wb");
        if (fread(avg_temps, avg_temps_size * sizeof(double), 1, f) != 1) {
            /* oops something went wrong */
        }
        fclose(f);
        /* Do something with array */
    }
```

Comment: Using `6 * sizeof(double)` (twice) is a long-winded way of writing `sizeof(avg_temps)` — and fragile too.  Using `sizeof` means there's no need to alter the `fwrite()` or `fread()` calls even if the size of the array changes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: My hypothesis is this will eventually be a heap array. Maybe I should change that literal 6 to a const.

Comment: Fair enough — certainly, once it is heap allocated, the size calculation changes, but the 6 becomes more of a liability then.